# Hiding url in navigation bar

Tags: url, redirect

Is it possibile to hide the last part of url (after ?) and show only video.php or something else in the browsers navigation bar ??

```
http://mysite.com/video.php?url=thisisvideono66
```

Regards

Comment: did you found any acceptable answer or any other finding...

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP's `POST` method of submitting your `form` to avoid those characters. To access the variable on the receiving page, use `$_POST["VARIABLE"];`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to HTML/JSP code than use `HTTP POST` instead of `HTTP GET` that way you can hide the request parameters .
Or if you want to implement it application wide use a URL Rewriter.